# OpenVPN Access Server manual configuration

Tags: openvpn

We had a running OpenVPN AS at our office that suddenly stopped working (even the web administration completely refuses connections. The browser explicity claims that the site refused to connect to https://localhost:943)
These are the facts:
The server has two network interfaces, *eth0* and *eth1* (to listen to exposed services like FTP)
At some (unknown) time *eth1* was renamed to *enp5s0* I guess due to
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/
I installed *webmin* and after login for the first time it complained that some firewall rules had to be "fixed" (I'm not sure if such fixing caused the problem since the VPN was not used but after a few days)
OpenVPN service (openvpnas) is up and running

The problem with the VPN was discovered (among other services that stopped working also) and then I found that *enp5s0* got a new IP address, so I forwarded the appropiate ports (TCP/943 and UDP/1194) to such new IP
Some services ran again with other forwardings to the new IP

I guess there are two solutions here:
Rename *enp5s0* back to *eth1*, but as I read that it's not recommended and I'm not sure if it has something to do with OpenVPN (I stopped the ufw service and the problem persisted)
Somehow configure OpenVPN to listen to the new IP and/or interface

Since the OpenVP AS web admin is unaccesible, how can I configure it? I would not like to use this:
https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/section-faq-openvpn-as/69-virtual-appliance/433-why-cant-i-access-the-adminclient-ui.html
since it claims it will completely wipe out the (very hard to tune) configuration (where it is located by the way?)

Any solution to this mess?

Answer (score 3):

After some digging I realized the configuration files (sqlite databases) are located at:
*/usr/local/openvpn_as/etc/db*
In particular *config.db* holds several parameters and the *value* column holds (as its name implies) a value for the parameter in the *name* column.
(sqlite is needed upon here. You can install it with 
*sudo apt-get install sqlite*)
So, enter:
*sudo service openvpnas stop*
*cd /usr/local/openvpn_as/etc/db*
*sudo sqlite3 config.db*
Check the (second) interface listening:
SELECT * FROM config where value='eth1';  // or whatever your **previous** second interface is. This step is just for checking
Now update the value:
*update config set

value='enp5s0' // or whatever your **new** second interface is

where value='eth1';*
*.exit*
*sudo service openvpnas start*
After that, OpenVPN was up and running again

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command

Detected an existing OpenVPN-AS configuration.
Continuing will delete this configuration and restart from scratch.
Please enter 'DELETE' to delete existing configuration: DELETE

/usr/local/openvpn_as/bin/ovpn-init